# How to connect android bluetooth with arduino?

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I want to make an android app that would connect with bluetooth module and send ASCII values for forward, back, right and left buttons pressed on app. 
I have worked on android using android studio. Can I make this app for arduino using android studio or I would have to use some other tool?
Explain the logic (and code if you can), try to avoid links.

Comment: What have you done with arduino and bluetooth? What have you tried?

Comment: Actually I have made a car that is controlled by android app using bluetooth. I have almost completed the hardware part and I have also tested it with some app but that app doesn't have the functionality I want therefore I want to make my own @MorrisonChang

Answer (score 0):

A good step in between, could be [Arduino with Processing](http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Processing). As it provides a relative Java like language, from which you control the Arduino. (Under the hood, actual Java is used).

See [Arduino Processing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLfJQHrd6Ug&list=PLu5iICvWkqKvoe2FWvqKA3dAWkxWN3IHk) introduction videos.

Ones that is working, it should be relative strait forward to convert that to Java.